# Sprint Boot @Valid is not throwing the message as described

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot, and learning by doing it. I saw couple of videos and there they are showing to use `@Valid` keyword before the `@RequestBody`. But if i am doing so i am getting the error but not as expected.

> I am hitting this URL with method = POST http://localhost:8080/users
> and i am getting this reponse. NO Error Message as defined.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-04-30T08:35:24.384+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/users"
}
```

sharing the controller file

> User Controller.java

```
package xyz.fastview.testing.ui.controller;    
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import xyz.fastview.testing.ui.mode.request.UserDetailRequestModel;
import xyz.fastview.testing.ui.model.response.UserRest;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping()
    public String createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDetailRequestModel userAccount) {
        return "Working Fine...!";
    }
}
```

> UserDetailsRequestMode.java

```
package xyz.fastview.testing.ui.mode.request;

import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class UserDetailRequestModel {
    @NotNull(message = "firstName cannot be null")
    private String firstName;
    
    @NotNull(message = "lastName cannot be null")
    private String lastName;
    
    @NotNull(message = "email cannot be null")
    @Email(message = "email should be a proper email address")
    private String email;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 8, max = 20, message = "Password length can be 8 to 20 characters")
    private String password;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Comment: Put you example JSON please

Comment: `{
    "lastName": "lastname",
    "email": "ankit@gmail.com",
    "password": "12345678"
}`

Answer (score 1):

Turn on custome messages for validator in your `application.properties` or `application.yml`. YAML for example:

```yaml
server.error.include-message: always
```

Since version 2.3, Spring Boot hides the `message` field in the response to avoid leaking sensitive information.

Comment: I am able to see the some error in the console of Spring tool suite, but response body doesn't contains anything. Still the same error message body getting without specified that firstname is required.

`{
    "timestamp": "2021-04-30T09:02:27.016+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/users"
}`

Answer (score 0):

Controller advice is better solution for handle web error messages.

You can try below code also you can enrich response model.

```
@ResponseBody
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public Map<String, String> handleValidationExceptions(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
            String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
            String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
            errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
        });
        return errors;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the following POST json request to your controller:

```
{"lastName":"lastname","email": "ankit@gmail.com", "password": "12345678"}
```

There is the missing parameter field `firstName` you declared as a `NotNull` field in your `UserDetailRequestModel` class with the annotation `@NotNull`:

```
public class UserDetailRequestModel {
    @NotNull(message = "firstName cannot be null")
    private String firstName;
    ... other fields
}
```

Indeed following your class definition an example of one correct json is the following:

```
{"firstName":"firstname", "lastName":"lastname","email": "ankit@gmail.com", "password": "12345678"}
```

The absence of an error message is due to the fact you haven't used the [`BindingResult`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html) as a parameter like I'm using below in your rewritten method:

```
@PostMapping()
    public String createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDetailRequestModel userAccount,
            BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println(bindingResult.getAllErrors());
        }
        return "Working Fine...!";
    }
```

The method [`getAllErrors`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#getAllErrors--) get all errors, both global and field ones, I'm printing it a primitive way, but the message is quite explicative that `firstName` parameter cannot be null:

[Field error in object 'userDetailRequestModel' on field 'firstName': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.userDetailRequestModel.firstName,NotNull.firstName,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [userDetailRequestModel.firstName,firstName]; arguments []; default message [firstName]]; default message [firstName cannot be null]]

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you need to perform to show the validation message as part of the REST API response.

1. Remove the below dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. Also you need to define an Exception Handler to propagate the message to the consumer.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public Map<String, String> handleValidationExceptions(
  MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
    ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
        String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
        String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
        errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
    });
    return errors;
}
```

Please refer to the tutorial for further assistance: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation

Comment: They are not mentioning in which class we should put the method.Link is not helpful.